# Apache Spark Join Performance

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 tables, T1 and T2.
T1 is read from Postgres and smaller in size, but gradually increases in volume) (from 0 to hiveTableSize).
T2 is read from Hive and bigger in size (more than 100k rows).

I am doing LEFT_ANTI join as

```
T1.join(T2, column_name, "LEFT_ANTI").
```

The goal is to get all rows from T1 which are not in T2. After all transformations, the data would be written to Postgres and the whole data would be read again when the job runs the next day.

What I am observing is, smallTable.join(largeTable) => does it have performance impact. My job runs anywhere from 30min to 90min with the above join, but if I comment this join out, it runs in less than 5 min.

Does Spark optimize large table joined against small table?

Answer (score 0):

If the larger table is in fact only 100K rows, this join should run in seconds. There is something other than the join performance causing the bottleneck. One potential issue is that the number of partitions you have is too large. This leads to a lot of overhead when processing small data sets.

Try something like the following

```
T1.coalesce(n).join(T2.coalesce(n), column_name, "LEFT_ANTI")
```

Where **n** is some small integer, ideally 2 * the number of executor cores available. the coalesce function reduces the number of partitions in the data set. Honestly, at this scale, you may even want coalesce to 1 partition.

Note also that the tables are likely being read completely into Spark before the join. Because you are join across two federated sources, the only way to do the anti-join is to pull both tables into Spark scan both of them. This could be contributing to poor performance. It may even be worthwhile to copy the PG table into Spark before the join depending one where else it is being used.

Comment: Very good comment and i was also on the same page. I ll give a go about the re-partition and see how it goes. I am already reading the Hive table completely and as well as Postgres. Where i was totally bewildered was, few lines down this join, am doing "largeTable.join(smallTable)" and that worked fine. Anyways, some directions to try.. and thanks!